# Hazelcast Delta Updates

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am looking for some way to do delta updates within hazelcast for a large set of data (1 Million+ of records)

The use case is that a map of objects is given the hazelcast client, within the values of the map only certain fields are populated and the rest are null. 
We want to replace the fields for the entry  if they are changed but if they are null or the same no change would happen.

We currently do this using entry processor but i believe the Map we pass in constructor would be sent to every member of the cluster which is inefficient..
Is there any better way of doing this?

```java
private Map mapOfNewValues;

public DomainClassDeltaUpdateEntryProcessor(Map mapOfNewValues) {
  this.mapOfNewValues = mapOfNewValues;
}

@Override
public Object process(Map.Entry<String, DomainClass> entry) {
  DomainClass oldDomain = entry.getValue();
  if (oldDomain != null) {
    DomainClass newDomainObj = (DomainClass) map.get(entry.getKey());
    if (newDomainObj != null) {
      entry.setValue(getDelta(oldDomain,newDomainObj));
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Called using

```java
 map.executeOnKeys(deltaMap.keySet(), new DomainClassDeltaUpdateEntryProcessor(deltaMap));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look on the client side & use `executeOnKey` instead. This way, you can send the update for each ket with a separate call so  if you have 1000 keys in the maps & 4 members, instead of sending all 1000 updates to all 4 members, you only send 100 updates distributed between 4 members & each call will only contains 1 delta object.

So on the client side, you can do something like this:

```
mapOfNewValues.entrySet().forEach(e -> if(e.getValue() != null) map.executeOnKey(e.getKey(), new DomainClassDeltaUpdateEntryProcessor(e.getValue())));
```

Comment: This would create 1 million entry processors (since my delta map will be ~1 million entries)... Is that something hazelcast can handle reasonably well? I would have imagined there would be a overhead for each entryProcessor instance and this would result in heavy CPU usage.

Comment: @Froodle your approach will create 1M+ entry processor & some of them wont even do any operation since you're sending all updates to all nodes. What I'm suggesting, instead of iterating through mapKeys, iterate through your delta map & send update to that specific node/partition that holds that value. Of course, if you have update for all 1M keys, both will be same but if you have only 1K keys to update, there'll be only 1K Entry Processor call, instead of 1M